# Filtering matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I'm a beginner in Matlab and I'm trying to filter a matrix

```
A=[104 104 100 108 108; 104 104 100 108 108; 99 99 106 98 98; 95 95 90 85 85; 95 95 90 85 85]
```

with the filter

```
B=[-0.1111111111111111 -0.1111111111111111 -0.1111111111111111; -0.1111111111111111 0.8888888888888889 -0.1111111111111111; -0.1111111111111111 -0.1111111111111111 -0.1111111111111111]
```

the method I have to use for padding is replication, so I changed the matrix A to become

```
A=[104 104 100 108 108; 104 104 100 108 108; 99 99 106 98 98; 95 95 90 85 85; 95 95 90 85 85]
```

when I tried to make the inner product between the matrix and the filter to get the filtered matrix

```
dot(A,B)
```

I got the error:

```
_________ Error using dot (line 33) A and B must be same size.
_________
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the dot product is ***not*** filtering an image. If you want to filter the image with the filter you've provided, you can use [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) to do that.

Also, it handles the replication padding automatically by passing the [`replicate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html#inputarg_options) input parameter.

```
output = imfilter(A, B, 'replicate');
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! those three lines you wrote is very helpful more than the minutes wasted in searching websites and watching videos that doesn't answer my question